# UltraVNC server host::display

Tags: vnc

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно обозначить хост+имякомпьютера, если я хочу подключиться не из подсети, а все серверы висят на одном белом IP?

Т.е., например:
**Server**(255.255.255.255) [comp№1(192.168.0.1), comp№2(192.168.0.2), comp№3(192.168.0.3)]

**Viewer**(100.100.100.100)

а мне нужно подключиться к comp№2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все серверы висят на одном белом IP - это как ? Если у вас 1 внешни нужно делать переброс портов каждый хост свой port

Comment: т.е. на роутере сделать через NAT: Port Forward (использую PSense)?

Comment: Именно, так и нужно сделать

Comment: поправил ответ ! на каждый ip свой порт

Comment: А если IP на локальных компьютерах динамический? Есть возможность привязки к имени компьютера?

Comment: если есть DNS сервер с оформленными локальными именами то можно, в др. случае прописать маки на DHCP что б одни и  те же выдавались